# IIS intranet link directly to hard disc folder

Tags: iis-7

I'm trying to use IIS 7 to run an HTML5 app via localhost directly out of the folder of the GIT repository where I am developing files (e.g. I go to [ip address]/myApp and it runs C:/git/myApp/index.html).

So I set up a new web site in IIS that has the following advanced settings:

```
Application Pool: myApp
Bindings: http:*:80:newAutoDemo
ID: 2
Name: myApp
Physical Path: C:/git/myApp
Physical Path Credentials Login type: Interactive
Start Automatically: true
```

However, when I try to go to [ip address]/myApp, it looks for files in C:/inetpub/wwwroot/myApp instead of my GIT directory (throwing a 404 error). Any idea how to fix it so that it links directly?

Note: I would like this to run on other computers on the same LAN as well as the computer with IIS running.

Comment: [ip address]/myApp would be how "Virtual Directories" are set up, not web sites.  You have to use the new binding to get to that folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new WebSite in IIS means that it's no longer under the default `http://localhost/` site. Looks like you've got it set up to respond to `http://newAutoDemo`, so you'd need to make sure your DNS points that domain name to this IP address (if you're testing from a single machine, you can do it in the `hosts` file).

If you want to access it as `http://{ipaddress}/myApp`, then rather than creating a brand new website in IIS, you'll just want a new virtual directory or application underneath `Default Web Site`.

Comment: I was able to access it correctly from the same computer by editing the hosts file. Would I need to be a network admin in order to make it work the same way for the whole LAN?

Comment: Actually, using a virtual directory was exactly what I wanted. But for some other reason I can't get other computers to connect to IIS...

Comment: If you were doing the separate website thing, you would need to have your network team modify the DNS for the whole network - or else every user would have to modify their hosts file.

Comment: If other machines on your network can't access the default website on this machine, then it's still a network thing - maybe a firewall rule, or maybe just machines unable to talk to each other based on their location within the network.

Comment: It turned out to be a firewall issue on my machine. Running the command listed in Sohail's answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238830/how-to-enable-world-wide-services-http-in-the-firewall-using-command-line) fixed it.