# SSRS troubleshoot Report Manager URL

Tags: sql-server, internet-explorer, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

all
I have SQL 2012 BI, tried to make local service and no matter what can't make that  active.
My Computer name = T410,  Default Instance of db = MSSQLServer

I went thru SSRS Config Manager, set all like below:

Service Account:  Use build-in Account.  = Networks Services

Web Service URL:  http://T410:80/ReportServer

Database:  added new db  ReportServer, use SQL Server Added account with DBA rights  (before I tried W auth and it also didn't work)

Report Manager URL: http://T410:80/Reports
Got all green OK statuses for each of case....

Went thru this video setting IE tool/security settings/ adding local URL
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nItx9xaJJi4

And still can't make that bloody http://T410/Reports  active, getting 404 error.

In SQL Server config manager have my sql server and SSRS running, and SQL server browser too...

Is there any way to troubleshoot this situation, what is can be wrong. I totally got crazy, looks like tried it all. I think it's till something around my accounts security. Can I see that URL somewhere running in Task Manager ?

Please help!!! SAVE OUR SSRS !!!

Comment: Are you specifying the url EXACTLY as you've got it in config, ie including the port number?

Comment: Are you trying the URL on the server or another computer? Can you first try `http://localhost/Reports` on the server and see the result?

Comment: I'm all local, everything on same laptop, tried url with :80 port either, I clicked on url provided in configuration manager and it's same 404.  Neither local/Reports or localhost/ReportServer works.  I also tried to use my machine name and assigned IP instead of  <localhost>.   Also opened imbound firewall rule for TCP on 80.                                   Should be some service name to check in Task Manager ?                 I also read about last option to reinstall  everything but want to make it work, excellent challenge 0)  Tx all

Comment: Also disabled my Kaspersky along with W Firewall

Comment: I also checking now to add HTTP service      like in this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238830/how-to-enable-world-wide-services-http-in-the-firewall-using-command-line             but hit missing helper AUTHFWDF6.DLL

Answer (score 7):

A bit late to the party, but I found this question because I ran into the same issue for some reason. Adding it to trusted sites didn't do the trick for me.

This was an SSRS instance that has been running with a client for years, but for some reason stopped working at some point.

The solution for me was to open the Reporting Services Configuration Manager, then to the Report Manager URL tab, selected the Virtual Directory field and then clicked APPLY without editing anything. It loaded for a while and then confirmed that the virtual directory was (re)created and the URL was reserved.

[image: Report Manager URL > APPLY]

Comment: This worked for me (I didn't even try the Trusted Sites fix). It turns out that on this new install I hadn't accepted the proposed URL configuration, assuming that the default values would automatically be configured. Not so. As noted in the answer, we have to click Accept to configure these defaults.

Answer (score 1):

BINGO !!!!!   Problem solved !!!!!
Need to do this thing to add those to trusted sites.

http://machinename and http://localhost need to be added as Trusted Sites in Internet Explorer. Tools/Option/Security/Trusted SItes.>

Thanks to all for help.
M

Answer (score 0):

First, try running Internet Explorer as Administrator and then browsing to your http://T410:80/Reports url for Report Manager. If this works, you need to then add your user account to the Content Manager role on the Home folder, and also assign your user account the System Administrator role in Site Settings.

If that doesn't work, it may be that something else on the server is already using the default port (80), so in Reporting Services Configuration Manager try changing the port used by the web service and Report Manager to something else (e.g. 8080) and then trying the new URL (including the port number e.g. http://T410:8080/Reports).

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue however the root cause in my case is little bit different.
Earlier both my Sql server instance & physical server have same name. After that we changed the name of physical server so my sql named instance have differed name and its not allowing SSRS to connect with old name. To solve the issue i have updated my sql server instance name to new physical served name and it solved the issue

```
sp_dropserver <'old_physical_server_name\instancename'>
GO
sp_addserver <'new_name\instancename'>, local
GO
```